# How do I debug a WordPress theme for IE9?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, internet-explorer-9

My WordPress blog ([www.itauthor.com](http://www.itauthor.com)) displays just fine in IE7, IE8, Chrome and Firefox. However, it doesn't display at all in IE9, even if I F12 and change the display modes. Disabling all active WordPress plugins doesn't solve the problem but switching to another theme does - so there's something in my theme that IE9 doesn't like.

However, I really like the theme I'm using, I've been using it for years and I really don't want to have to switch themes (and be faced with hours & hours of PHP tweaking) just because of IE9.

So what's the best way of tracking down what's causing IE9 to blank my site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

I eventually discovered the answer to blank pages in IE9 - or pages not displayed correctly for some sites. It's a known bug in IE9. It doesn't like Helvetica. This bug only manifests itself if you actually have Helvetica installed which is why most people don't encounter the problem, but if you do have Helvetica installed and you browse to a site like validator.w3.org that (at the time of writing) uses this font, then part or all of the page won't show up in IE9.

The solution for visiting other people's sites (a drastic one) is to uninstall Helvetica on your computer, then IE9 will just use the next installed font listed in the page's CSS.

If you're a web site owner and you want to fix your site for other people, the solution is to remove Helvetica from your site's stylesheets.

I find it amazing that months after this bug has been known about Microsoft still haven't got round to fixing it.

Answer (score 3):

Try passing your site through a validator to see potential problems.

http://validator.w3.org/

There are quite a few issues, it would be best to make sure that your markup matches your doctype. You should also remove any white spaces before the doctype declaration (there are 3 blank lines)

As your doctype is XHTML, you have to close your tags properly. The three css link tags on top is not closed, change them to:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.itauthor.com/wp-content/themes/blueprint/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.itauthor.com/wp-content/themes/blueprint/blueprint-wp.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.itauthor.com/wp-content/themes/blueprint/print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

You're also closing some paragraph tags where they're not open. Just work your way through the issues on the validator page.

Despite all problems, I have a fresh installation of IE9 with default settings, and your page renders just fine. If you have any IE add-ons installed, make sure you run IE9 without addons using the shortcut in the start menu and test again.

Comment: Thanks. I see my site is getting a _lot_ of validation errors. Strangely IE9 is not displaying http://validator.w3.org/ for me _either_ - I have to go there in Firefox. After reading that you could see my site in IE9 okay, I tried uninstalling my IE9 update, restarting, downloadeding IE9 again, installing it again & restarting, with no change: neither my site nor validator.w3.org displays (although other sites are fine). I'm using IE9 on Win7 64-bit. I wonder how many other people have noticed problems.

Comment: I'll correct those validation problems, but (given that validator.w3.org isn't displaying for me either and is, obviously, valid HTML) I don't think that's my problem.

Comment: Odd, I think I'm out of ideas for now. For the record, I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit.

Comment: I did some googling, try disabling hardware rendering, see this article: blastingvolume.com/2010/09/internet-explorer-9-blank-pages-fix.html Although I don't see a reason why it wouldn't affect all websites. Also make sure your graphics drivers are up to date.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that. No luck. However, looking in the F12 pane I can see all of the page content is in there - it's just not displaying. However, if I remove all the CSS links the text and images all show up as expected (but obviously the page looks terrible). I reinstated the CSS links and installed Fiddler, but it's not showing up any problems getting the CSS files from the server. It just seems there's something in IE9 that doesn't want to play with the CSS when it gets it.

Comment: However, this leaves 2 questions: 1) Why doesn't switching to another display mode work? 2) Why don't some other sites work - e.g. if I go to the W3 CSS validator at http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ I get a blank white page and switching modes has no effect - so I'm guessing it isn't a CSS problem *there*!

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

as a workaround until the problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, after adding that to my header.php file, pages still don't display (for me) in IE9.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->   
    <script src="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_45311/wp-content/themes/CherryFramework/js/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js" type="text/javascript">    </script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">    
        jQuery(function(){    
            jQuery('.sf-menu').mobileMenu({defaultText: "Navigate to..."});    
        });    
    </script>    
    <!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: It is preferable to include a brief explanation, rather than just code. Can you update your answer with a brief summary of how the code solves the problem?

Comment: Yeah as @Leigh suggested , If you add some more description to what your code does , It will not only help the OP but also other users who is looking for a similar content as such ... btw if they like it , you get **upvoted** too ! ;)